# What should i do with the company?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, job-offer, human-resources, company-policy

I am working in a company as an intern and got a job offer from another company with tentative DOJ, they asked to get resignation mail acceptance to proceed with an offer letter,
now they not giving the offer letter it's been one month after receiving the job offer mail,
still, now I didn't receive an offer letter, every time they are mentioned lame reasons that some internal issues, some permission issues like that, they every time asking to wait for one more week like that, what should I do now?

Comment: "resignation mail acceptance" What is this?

Comment: Please consider using periods to break your sentences apart.

Comment: Are you from India? You may want to add that to your question, because "resignation acceptance" is unheard of in other countries. India is very special in that regard.

Comment: 'resignation mail acceptance' sounds like some variant of relieving letter

Comment: @nvoigt By the user name, I would guess India is a safe bet, and it sounds like a relieving letter, or something akin to that

Comment: in India, relieving letter/experience certificate will provide after serving notice period, job offered company wants a confirmation that I will join their company, they want something official that proves to them that I have resigned and they accepted it , so they process with the offer letter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they're messing you around this much over providing a simple thing like an offer letter then it's not looking good - they *might* still come through but I think it's highly unlikely at this point.

So sorry to say it but you need to resume your job-search (if you stopped that is) - if you want to stay at your existing position you probably want to talk to them ASAP and see if they will allow you to retract your resignation.

In the future **do not** resign from an existing position without an offer letter in hand. It's a hard lesson to learn but that is an easy way to be left high and dry.

Comment: "In the future do not resign from an existing position without an offer letter in hand" I'm not so sure that this applies in India, given the legal requirements around relieving letters.